Prefix code and twenty-question games?
This is going to be a simple question.  I'm following the book "Elements of information theory" by Thomas M. Cover. He state the equivalence between coding and "designing a series of questions" for each object in the 20-question game. Why is it that the optimal code(prefix-free and least expected coding length) an efficient coding to optimize the number of questions asked in a 20-question game? What does it have to do with the prefix property?
We only need the "least expected coding length" property only, do we?

When would asking questions stop?

The prefix-free property relates to the fact that we ask sequential questions (with yes/no binary answers) and each answer determines the next question asked [in terms of belonging to a subset] and becomes a label of the branch corresponding to that answer in the sequence of answers.
This means that the collection of possible answer sequences form a binary tree, where we stop if and only if the unknown number is uniquely determined. This means that no sequence of possible answers leading to a unique number is a prefix of another valid sequence of possible answers.

Thats one way to put it. Or, if a collection of questions already determines a specific object in the game. Ask more questions is useless. So, designing the series of questions reduces down to designing prefix code.
